# How to connect iPhone hotspot to range extender using ethernet? Is this feasible?

Tags: network, ethernet, iphone

How can I use Ethernet to extend my iPhone hotspot? Is it possible?
Hi everyone,

I want to use an Ethernet cable to extend the range of my iPhone hotspot. I have a lightning cable and an Ethernet cable, but I don't know how to connect them. Do I need a special adapter that has a male Ethernet connector and a male lightning connector (I did not find one like that on the internet)? Or is there another way to do it? I would appreciate any advice or suggestions. I'm not sure if an [Ethernet female-to-male lightning adapter would work for me or not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0X6u.png)
[image: thernet female-to-male lightning adapter]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMJU2ZM/A/belkin-ethernet-power-adapter-with-lightning-connector ?